# Delay displaying a LoginViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have this app that uses an accessToken that only remains for two hours. My app has three UINavigationController (with UITableViewController) inside a UITabBarController. Every time I click on one of my tabs, a new connection is created and I check if the statusCode of the HTTP response is 200 or 401. If the statusCode is 401 is because my accessToken is no longer operative and I have to relog again.

The problem I have is that when the current viewController calls the LoginViewController because the 401, the LoginViewController shows with delay and you can see the cells of UITableViewController.

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[CaseCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

    if (self.accessToken == nil) {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self refresh];

    }
}

- (void)refresh
{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myURL", self.accessToken];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];

        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
            self.cases = responseArray;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
                [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
        });
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

I really don't know what is the problem. I mean, I know it has to be related with things happening in background and **dispatch_async** but I've made everything and I don't know why this **delay**.

PD: Don't pay attention to NSUserDefaults. I know I have to store the token in Keychain.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Have you tried placing the if statement in other view controller lifecycle methods? For example, and I write this having never tried, maybe you could place the `if (self.accessToken == nil) {...` statement in `loadView` (i.e. executes before `viewDidLoad`). Alternatively, overlay the screen with a translucent white `UIView` subview (followed by a `bringSubviewToFront:` method) in `viewDidLoad`, then on completion of your `LoginViewController` method you could `removeFromSuperview` that translucent cover subview.

Comment: Still not working. I'm going to try the **bringSubviewToFrot** that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

that gets called by your UITabBarController to check that the session is still valid, and then either proceed to the view controller or launch your login controller. If you try adding it to the view controller's view before the view loads, it won't have anything to add it to, and if you call it after the view loads, you're going to see the original view before it can launch the login screen.

Comment: Yeah, I'm agree with you. I'm going to try this. Thanks!!